# Android Emulator - The camera always takes photo in landscape mode?

Tags: android, emulation

I've just noticed this quirk with android emulators. They seem to always photo in landscape mode, even when the phone is in portrait mode. This isn't a problem when running the actual code on a live device.

Why does android emulator do that?